# How to retrieve metadata from a video file

Tags: java, video, timestamp, metadata

I recorded a video using my phone. Now, for my desktop application, I need to retrieve the timestamp of when I start recording video.
I suppose I have to access metadata, so I tried using JMF (which I use to play video on my app), but I think it doesn't provide metadata of a video file, or until now I've not found it!
If I use the class java.util.Properties, using the list method it doesn't retrieve anything (returns an empty list).
If I use the java.io.File, I can only retrieve the last modified of the file, but not of the video.

So how can I retrieve the time of starting recording video?
Please help me!
Dodo

Comment: using JMF to playing video, I need an avi or mpeg file

Comment: update: I've found a java library named "JAVE", which allows you to get info like duration, video size, bitrate, codec, etc. and to encode a video file extracting video and/or audio track.
Now I don't know how to retrieve the start timestamp of the video: is it right to calculate it as "file's last modified - duration", assuming that the file is created when you finish to record it?